# Can't declare two character pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why does c allow initialization of string without declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099983/why-does-c-allow-initialization-of-string-without-declaration)

I am trying this rather simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void copy(char *,char *);
main() {
char *name;
char *surname;
printf("Enter name: ");
scanf("%s",name);

printf("%s",name);
}
```

But for some reason, after I enter a name and press `Enter`, the program hangs and gives a message like **Program has stopped working.** However when I remove the 2nd character pointer declaration, that is the `char *surname;`, it works just as expected. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

You have not allocated memory for the pointers, so the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) accesses arbitrary unspecified memory, which is undefined behaviour.

You need to pass pointers to sufficiently large memory blocks to scanf, either declare

```
char s1[100], s2[100];
```

(if 100 is large enough), or [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) memory

```
char *s1 = malloc(100);
char *s2 = malloc(100);
if (!s1 || !s2) {
    // malloc failure
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writting into unallocated memory. That is `undefined behavior`,

You can do 2 things here:

1. declare your arrays of chars as having a fixed size at compile-time like this: `char name[100];` (which means you can't change their size at runtime)
2. allocate room for `char *name` using [malloc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or [calloc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) functions in `stdlib.h`

In any case you absolutely **have to** make sure you only allow the user to input the amount of bytes you allocated, otherwise bad things can and will happen!

A small study on what an evil person can (and will ;) do if you fail to define said boundaries can be found here: http://www.cultdeadcow.com/cDc_files/cDc-351/

Comment: I don't understand. Why then, it works if the second declaration is removed?

Comment: as i said.. "unedfined behavior" you are writing "somewhere" into unstructurd memory.. anything can happen and what will happen depends on the compiler and/or platform. most likely the kernel realizes that you are illegaly overwriting a pointer you declared right after the first one (which makes it likely that you write into it right at the 2nd character) and prevents you from doing that.

Comment: @Cupidvogel UB doesn't mean the program **will** crash, it means the program **can** crash.

Comment: @GungFoo Also, please add the stack-based (automatic) array option to your answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 i made your requested edits + added some fun stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't allocate memory for it, and the string you put in it screws the code of the program. Try to use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) and [getline](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/sscanf.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int nbytes = 100;
  char *my_string;
  int int1, int2, int3;
  int args_assigned;

  args_assigned = 0;

  while (args_assigned != 3)
    {
      puts ("Please enter three integers separated by whitespace.");
      my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
      getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);
      args_assigned = sscanf (my_string, "%d %d %d", &int1, &int2, &int3);
      if (args_assigned != 3)
    puts ("\nInput invalid!");
    }

  printf ("\nThanks!\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", int1, int2, int3);

  return 0;
}
```

check out this:

[Reading in a variable length string user input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672560/reading-in-a-variable-length-string-user-input-in-c)

and this :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Answer (score 1):

You declare a pointer and do not give it a valid memory address, it points to a random addrss. You cannot read or write with this pointer. Pointers should be used like this:

```
char s1[100],s2[100];
char * name=s1;
char * surname=s2;
```

Comment: Why those extraneous pointers? Just pass `s1` and `s2` to `scanf()`.

Comment: Thanks. Another question, pointers, whatever they point to, are themselves actually integers storing addresses, right? So `*p = "foo"` will place some integer value into `p`, which will be the address where the program has stored **foo**, right? How come then we can assign strings to `p`, like `p = "barbar"`?

Comment: char *p; *p ="foo" is wrong. p="foo" is right. because in C, strings are char pointers.

Comment: (1)Yes, pointers are actually integers, more accurately, special integers which value is memory address. In some IDE, you can assign a integer to a pointer `char * p =10;`  And we can add some value to a pointer: `p+=20;`  Of course, when you add an number  N to a pointer, the value of the pointer will increase not N but N*sizeof ( element ).  (2)Your code: `char *p; *p ="foo";` is wrong. `p="foo"` is right. because in C, strings are char pointers. Pointers should be assigned to pointers.

Comment: @H2CO3: Just use `s1` and `s2` is OK. But the author of the question want to know how to use pointer. So I must use pointer as a demo.